# select tag, not getting style using class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```
= f.select :correct_answer,
              options_for_select([ "Respuesta Uno", "Respuesta Dos",
              "Respuesta Tres",  "Respuesta Cuatro", "Respuesta Cinco"]), {}, {:class => "form-control", :tabindex => 8}
```

but the select, it not getting the style

Answer (score 0):

Style has to be fifth parameter. You are missing attributes.

```
select(:model, :attribute, @options_for_select, { }, { :style => 'some: style' }
```

Try following:

```
f.select :correct_answer, {},
              options_for_select([ "Respuesta Uno", "Respuesta Dos",
              "Respuesta Tres",  "Respuesta Cuatro", "Respuesta Cinco"]), {}, {:class => "form-control", :tabindex => 8}
```

Comment: Try this <%= f.select :correct_answer, options_for_select([ "Respuesta Uno", "Respuesta Dos","Respuesta Tres"]), {},  {:style => "color:red;", :tabindex => 8} %>, User your own style in place of "color:red"

Comment: Thanks, but I have a class for this, so I don't want to embed the style on the select controller, also it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the `class` parameter in the nested hash like that, just make it its own argument:

```
= f.select :correct_answer,
           options_for_select([ "Respuesta Uno",
                                "Respuesta Dos",
                                "Respuesta Tres",  
                                "Respuesta Cuatro", 
                                "Respuesta Cinco" ]),
           tabindex: 8,
           class: "form-control"
```